# FOS user bundle authentication

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

How [FOS User Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/) authenticates the user by this service container?

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

I want to manipulate the authentication process. Where should I look in the bundle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually FOSUserBundle doesn't do authentication. It actually provides a db user provider. Authentication part is done by Symfony2's internal `form_login` authentication provider. If you want to create custom authentication provider check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) cookbook entry.

Comment: Thank you - the answer I've been looking for....! I have been trying to create an event listener to modify the authentication process for FOSUserBundle but couldn't find any leads; this is the only answer I've come across that says FOSUserBundle doesn't do authentication :)